# Why would Spring create 2 objects from Singleton class?

Tags: java, spring, scope

I may be wrong here , but i am unable to figure out why is Spring creating  2 different objects from a Singleton class. Following is the code:

```
public class DbSingleTOn {

    private static DbSingleTOn dbSingleTOn = new DbSingleTOn();
    private DbSingleTOn() {
    }
    public static DbSingleTOn getInstance() {
        return dbSingleTOn;
    }
}

public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                "spring-singleton.xml");
        DbSingleTOn dbSingleTOn = context.getBean(DbSingleTOn.class);
        System.out.println(dbSingleTOn.hashCode());

        DbSingleTOn dbSingleTOn1 = context.getBean(DbSingleTOn.class);
        System.out.println(dbSingleTOn1.hashCode());

        context.registerShutdownHook();
    }
}

Output:
18885489
17045421
```

Spring Config XML:

```
<bean id="bean1" class="com.singleton.DbSingleTOn" scope="prototype" >
    </bean>
```

It is expected to get different object for a normal class using "prototype" scope, however, Why would "prototype" create 2 objects from Singleton class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things. One, Spring has no idea (and really doesn't care) how your class is setup. The fact that you've implemented a programming pattern means nothing to Spring. Two, Spring uses reflection to instantiate the bean types you declare and therefore can use your `private` constructors.

Every time you request a prototype scoped bean from Spring, it will create a new instance of the bean.

Comment: @Scotirios I had a hunch that Spring must be loading classes via reflection , hence the expected behavior. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 3):

Just because you create a singleton in a static field this does not have an impact on spring. Spring is simply not aware of that.

Prototype scope just means: return a new instance when `getBean` is called.

Singleton scope means: create an instance once and always return this one.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't setup directly how to instantiate the bean, Spring use reflection to call a constructor for create beans. In addition use of default singleton scope, you can also setup `factory-method` in your xml config to `getInstance` to tell Spring how to create your beans.